# ASP.NET Jquery ReferenceError: System is not defined

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

simple thing: I want to call a C# function in aspx.cs from aspx-Page.

My C# Function (Kalender.aspx.cs):

```
protected JsonResult GetEvents()
    {
        //DATABASE READOUT
        using (DatabaseEntities dc = new DatabaseEntities())
        {
            var events = dc.Events.ToList();
            JsonResult json = new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            return json;
        }
    }
```

My JS call (Kalender.aspx):

```
        //DATABASE READOUT
        var json

        try { //DIRECT CALL
            var data = <%= GetEvents()%>;  //<<-- throw ReferenceError: System is not defined
            alert('DIRECT CALL: ' + typeof (data) + ' | ' + data[0]);
            json = JSON.parse(data);
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error + "\r" + error.name + "\r" + error.message);
        }
```

The JsonResult from GetEvents() include a [Events]-Object stored in a SQL. So a 
I add a ADO.NET Entity Data Model:

```
public partial class Events
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> End { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public bool IsFullDay { get; set; }
}
```

If the Model would'n work <%= GetEvents()%> throw correct error: "Model is not defined".

So what is the point of the Error "System is not defined". I spend hours and hours and find no solution. please help, thankful for any response.

(The worst thing in my life: yesterday everything works fine, the damn var accept the JsonResult and I could read out the data. In the morning I clean up the code. Rename some stuff. Armageddon. Nothing works anymore and I restart from beginning, don't know what goes wrong. I'am sad. :( )

EDIT ###

Console output:

```
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.RemoteDependency","time":"2018-04-02T11:49:50.7556362Z","tags":{"ai.internal.nodeName":"LAPTOP-81CNBL6C","ai.operation.parentId":"Y67fpD/L2MI=","ai.operation.name":"GET /Pages/Kalender","ai.operation.id":"Y67fpD/L2MI=","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"LAPTOP-81CNBL6C","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"rddf:2.2.0-738"},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB | C:\\USERS\\MARTIN\\DOCUMENTS\\VISUAL STUDIO 2017\\PROJECTS\\HOMEOFFICE\\HOMEOFFICE\\APP_DATA\\DATABASE.MDF","id":"zYD3G9N1sOI=","duration":"00:00:00.0110000","resultCode":"0","success":true,"type":"SQL","target":"(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB | C:\\USERS\\MARTIN\\DOCUMENTS\\VISUAL STUDIO 2017\\PROJECTS\\HOMEOFFICE\\HOMEOFFICE\\APP_DATA\\DATABASE.MDF","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Request","time":"2018-04-02T11:49:48.6739718Z","tags":{"ai.operation.name":"GET /Pages/Kalender","ai.operation.id":"Y67fpD/L2MI=","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"LAPTOP-81CNBL6C","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"web:2.2.0-738"},"data":{"baseType":"RequestData","baseData":{"ver":2,"id":"Y67fpD/L2MI=","name":"GET /Pages/Kalender","duration":"00:00:02.3570000","success":true,"responseCode":"200","url":"http://localhost:56879/Pages/Kalender","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}
```

Comment: Is there any errors on console?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes there is, I wrote it under EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

After hours and hours I found a simple solution.

I add to my C# Code:

```
return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(json.Data);
```

And accept that my function return string instead JsonResult:

```
        protected string GetEvents()
    {
        //DATABASE READOUT
        using (DatabaseEntities dc = new DatabaseEntities())
        {
            var events = dc.Events.ToList();
            JsonResult json = new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(json.Data);
        }
    }
```

JavaScript handel it well. [var] will understand the formation and cast automatically to json.